# Watchkit: How do I prevent the apple watch screen from turning off while my app is running?

Tags: watchkit

How can I programmatically disable the apple watch screen turn off while moving the watch around? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This is not possible with the current WatchKit APIs (even in watchOS 2).